# An equality between a product and a combinatorial sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, products

I'm trying to prove the following identity (of which I numerically verified the truth) :

$$\text{For every $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\lbrace-2k\text{ }|\text{ }k\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$,}$$

$$\text{$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}$}\left[1-\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}\right]=\frac{\alpha}{4^{n}}{2n \choose n}\text{$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}$}\frac{{n \choose k}^2}{{2n \choose 2k}}\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}$$

I've tried induction, unsuccessfully. Tbh, I don't really have any other ideas for tackling it. Products such as this are not that easy to work with.

Any ideas or suggestion ?

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us how you came up with this, that might provide a lead?

Comment: Well actually, I don't have more context either. It's some kind of "mathematical enigma" among many other proposed by a teacher at my uni, for enthousiastic students

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the identity

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\prod_{k=1}^n \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{2k+\alpha} \right]
= \frac{\alpha}{4^n} {2n\choose n}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2 {2n\choose 2k}^{-1} 
\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}}$$

we work with $n\ge 2$ and we first simplify the RHS

$$\frac{\alpha}{4^n} \frac{(2n)!}{n!\times n!}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!^2}{k!^2 (n-k)!^2} \frac{(2k)! (2n-2k)!}{(2n)!}
\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
\\ = \frac{\alpha}{4^n} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
\\ = \frac{1}{4^n} {2n\choose n} +  \frac{\alpha}{4^n} 
\sum_{k=1}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
.$$

Now for the LHS we find

$$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1+\alpha}{2k+\alpha}
= \prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1+\alpha)
\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
\\ = (1+\alpha) \prod_{k=2}^n (2k-1+\alpha)
\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+\alpha}.$$

We may apply partial fractions by residues to the two products (degree
of numerator  is less  than degree  of denominator  and poles  are all
simple) for the variable $\alpha$ and get

$$(1+\alpha) \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
\mathrm{Res}_{\alpha=-2k}
\prod_{q=2}^n (2q-1+\alpha)
\prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{2q+\alpha}
\\ = (1+\alpha) \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
\prod_{q=2}^n (2q-1-2k)
\prod_{q=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{2q-2k}
\prod_{q=k+1}^{n} \frac{1}{2q-2k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} 
(1+\alpha) \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
\prod_{q=2}^n (2q-1-2k)
\prod_{q=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{q-k}
\prod_{q=k+1}^{n} \frac{1}{q-k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} 
(1+\alpha) \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \frac{1}{(n-k)!} \prod_{q=2}^n (2q-1-2k).$$

For the remaining product we get

$$\prod_{q=2}^n (2q-1-2k)
= \prod_{q=2}^k (2q-1-2k) \prod_{q=k+1}^n (2q-1-2k)
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{k-1} (2k-2)!}{(k-1)! \times 2^{k-1}}
\prod_{q=1}^{n-k} (2q-1)
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{k-1} (2k-2)!}{(k-1)! \times 2^{k-1}} 
\frac{(2n-2k)!}{(n-k)! \times 2^{n-k}}.$$

Collecting everything we have for the partial fraction decomposition

$$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} 
(1+\alpha) \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \frac{1}{(n-k)!}
\frac{(-1)^{k-1} (2k-2)!}{(k-1)! \times 2^{k-1}} 
\frac{(2n-2k)!}{(n-k)! \times 2^{n-k}}$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{4^{n-1}} 
(1+\alpha) \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
{2k-2\choose k-1} {2n-2k\choose n-k}.}$$

Next to conclude  we extract the coefficient on  $[\alpha^q]$ and show
that the RHS and the LHS yield the same, proving the claim (no pole at
$\alpha=0$). We get for $q=0$ that we must have

$$\frac{1}{4^n} {2n\choose n} =
\frac{1}{4^{n-1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k}
{2k-2\choose k-1} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1}
{2k\choose k} {2n-2-2k\choose n-1-k}.$$

We recognize Catalan numbers with OGF

$$C(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}.$$

Continuing,

$$\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1}
{2k\choose k} [z^{n-1-k}] (1+z)^{2n-2-2k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} [z^{n-1}]
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1}
{2k\choose k} z^k (1+z)^{2n-2-2k}.$$

Now  when $k\gt  n-1$  there  is no  contribution  to the  coefficient
extractor and we continue with

$$\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-2}
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{k+1}
{2k\choose k} z^k (1+z)^{-2k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-2}
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z/(1+z)^2}}{2z/(1+z)^2}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} [z^{n}] (1+z)^{2n-2}
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z/(1+z)^2}}{1/(1+z)^2}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} [z^{n}] (1+z)^{2n-1}
(1+z-\sqrt{1-2z+z^2})
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} [z^{n}] (1+z)^{2n-1} 2z
= \frac{1}{2^{2n}} [z^{n-1}] 2 (1+z)^{2n-1}
= \frac{1}{2^{2n}} 2 {2n-1\choose n-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose n}.$$

We have equality for $q=0.$  For $q\ge 1$ we must have that

$$\frac{1}{4^n} 
\sum_{k=1}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
[\alpha^{q-1}] \frac{1}{2k} \frac{1}{1+\alpha/2/k}
\\ = \frac{1}{4^n} 
\sum_{k=1}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
(-1)^{q-1} \frac{1}{2^qk^q}$$

is the same as

$$\frac{1}{4^{n-1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^n ([\alpha^q] + [\alpha^{q-1}]) \frac{1}{2k+\alpha}
{2k-2\choose k-1} {2n-2k\choose n-k}.$$

This is

$$\frac{1}{4^{n-1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^n 
\left((-1)^q \frac{1}{2^{q+1} k^{q+1}} + 
(-1)^{q-1}\frac{1}{2^qk^q}\right)
{2k-2\choose k-1} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
\\ = \frac{1}{4^{n-1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^n 
\left(-\frac{1}{2k} + 1\right)
(-1)^{q-1}\frac{1}{2^qk^q}
{2k-2\choose k-1} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n-2}} 
\sum_{k=1}^n 
\frac{2k-1}{2k}
(-1)^{q-1}\frac{1}{2^qk^q} \frac{k}{2k-1}
{2k-1\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^n 
(-1)^{q-1}\frac{1}{2^qk^q}
{2k-1\choose k-1} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^n 
(-1)^{q-1}\frac{1}{2^qk^q} \frac{k}{2k}
{2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
\\ = \frac{1}{4^n} 
\sum_{k=1}^n 
(-1)^{q-1}\frac{1}{2^qk^q}
{2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}.$$

We again have equality. This concludes the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hard work !

Comment: Thank you. It will be interesting to see what other contributions appear regarding this challenging identity.

Comment: Actually, yesterday I found myself another lead that might provide a possibily quickier proof, relying more heavily on generating functions. I will write it down here when complete.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Very nice solution. It is interesting that the residual approach does not directly lead to the wanted sum. This all is worth a some more detailed analysis. Thanks for this inspiring contribution. (+1)

Comment: Thanks to you as well. I tried the usual residue technique for quite some time before seeing that it would not work here, at least as far as I was able to verify.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel:  Based upon your answer I think I could find a simplification.

Answer (score 4):

This is a mere supplement to @MarkoRiedels answer. Mimicking his solution with a slight change we can simplify the proof.

> We start with OP's left-hand side and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^n}&\color{blue}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}\right)}\\
> &=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1+\alpha}{2k+\alpha}\\
> &=\alpha\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1+\alpha)\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}\tag{1}\\
> &=\alpha\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}\mathrm{Res}_{\alpha=-2k}\prod_{q=1}^n(2q-1+\alpha)\prod_{q=0}^n\frac{1}{2q+\alpha}\\
> &=\alpha\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}\prod_{q=1}^n(2q-1-2k)\prod_{q=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{2q-2k}\prod_{q=k+1}^n\frac{1}{2q-2k}\\
> &=\frac{\alpha}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}(-1)^k\prod_{q=1}^k(2k+1-2q)\prod_{q=k+1}^n(2q-1-2k)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\prod_{q=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{q-k}\prod_{q=k+1}\frac{1}{q-k}\\
> &=\frac{\alpha}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}(-1)^k(2k-1)!!(2n-1-2k)!!\cdot\frac{1}{(-1)^kk!}\cdot\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\\
> &=\frac{\alpha}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}\cdot\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}\cdot\frac{(2n-2k)!}{2^{n-k}(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{1}{(-1)^kk!}\cdot\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\\
> &=\frac{\alpha}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}\cdot\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}{(2n)!}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\alpha}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2\binom{2n}{2k}^{-1}\frac{1}{2k+\alpha}}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) is the slight difference. Instead of factoring out $1+\alpha$ we multiply with $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha}$.

Comment: +1 for having short enough lines for my browser.

Comment: @J.G.: Thanks. I also have to cope sometimes with this bothering aspect and I know from experience that a proper layout is helpful to provide information.

Comment: (+1). This is clearly the better proof. Not having seen your initial manipulation (what you call the slight change) proved costly later on. Let it be a lesson to the reader.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for your generous comment.

Comment: @J.G. $\texttt{MSE}$ added recently a column to the left ( $\texttt{Home, Questions,...,Unanswered}$ ). It killed a lot of space for the answers. That was a bad design. Those links must be at the top as it was sometimes ago